# NullPointerException in game

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a space invaders type game in Java, but can't work out why the game won't work. Here's the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at UFO_Game.checkForHit(UFO_Game.java:131)
at UFO_Game.setup(UFO_Game.java:109)
at UFO_Game.run(UFO_Game.java:44)
at acm.program.Program.runHook(Program.java)
at acm.program.Program.startRun(Program.java)
at acm.program.Program.start(Program.java)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and here's the code getting the error.

```
public void checkForHit(){
    GObject CHECK = getElementAt(Bullet.getX(), Bullet.getY());
    if(CHECK == SHIP){
        removeAll();
    }
```

By the way, I'm using the ACM stuff like in the Stanford methodology.

Comment: go to the line it indicated (131) and check any variables there. Are they equal to null? If so you need to either change it to a value or set it equal to nothing. Like `String myString;`

Comment: Have you instantiated the `UFO_Game` object prior to calling `checkForHit()`?

Comment: -1 It is your job, as a developer, do determine *which* expression is null; from there is is only a small matter to find out *why* it is null. If you cannot deduce as such from a stack-trace, attach a debugger (a debugger is useful anyway).

Comment: Also, *there are many "duplicate" answers that explain what an NPE means and what might cause it in different situations*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that `Bullet` is a field in your `UFO_Game` class. It isn't assigned a valid value (object fields are initialized with `null`). When you try to invoke `getX()`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown. To avoid this, initialize the `Bullet` field when you construct each `UFO_Game` object.

By the way, methods and field names in Java should start with a lower case letter. Anyone familiar with Java will read `Bullet.getX()` as an invocation of a static (class) method.